# Selecionar mais vendidos em tabela relacionada

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Possuo uma tabela `pedidos`, `produtos` e outra `produtos_em_pedidos` descritas da seguinte forma:

```
produtos: id | nome
pedidos: id | data
produtos_em_pedidos: produto_id | pedido_id | quantidade
```

Eu preciso selecionar os produtos que mais ocorrem nos pedidos, podendo filtrar por data.

Um exemplo que já obtive foi encontrar os produtos mais vendidos globalmente, sem considerar a coluna quantidade, através da query:

`select produto_id, count(produto_id) from produtos_em_pedidos group by produto_id order by count(produto_id) desc`

Agora como eu filtraria isso pela data que está na tabela `pedidos` (ex: `WHERE data > 2015-01-01`) e como ainda multiplicaria o count pela coluna `quantidade`?

**EDIT:** Consegui filtar por datas através da seguinte query:

```
SELECT produto_id, count(produto_id) FROM produtos_em_pedidos
WHERE pedido_id in (select id from pedidos where data > '2015-01-01')
AND pedido_id in (select id from pedidos where data < '2018-01-01')
GROUP BY produto_id
order by count(produto_id) DESC;
```

Comment: É uma opção, outra boa seria usar um join entre as duas tabelas e utilizar os dados como desejado: `Select count(pep.produto_id) from produtos_em_pedidos pep join pedidos on(pep.pedido_id = pedidos.id and pedidos.data  < '2018-01-01' ) group by produto_id order by count(pep.produto_id) `, Mais ou menos assim.

Comment: E como eu consideraria a coluna `quantidade` no count?

Comment: O inner join só pega os registros que "batem" com a condição, então dando um count() ele contará os registros que se encaixam

Comment: O resultado final foi o mesmo. Mas esta forma que me passaste parece-me bem mais eficaz computacionalmente. Obrigado!

Comment: Opa, que bom que ajudou. Disponha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Agora como eu filtraria isso pela data que está na tabela pedidos (ex: WHERE data > 2015-01-01)?

Para isso basta fazer o join com a tabela que tem a data e checar a condição na cláusula *where*, da seguinte forma:

```
select produto_id, count(produto_id) as num_produto from produtos_em_pedidos join pedidos on (id = produto_id) where data > '2015-01-01' group by produto_id;
```

> e como ainda multiplicaria o count pela coluna quantidade?

Nesse caso você não vai conseguir apenas com uma query pois a consulta vai exigir a agregação da coluna quantidade ao *group by*. Para conseguir trazer a informação que você precisa, será necessária uma subquery para cada função de agregação. Para recuperar primeiro a quantidade de produtos, a seguinte query pode ser utilizada:

```
select produto_id, count(produto_id) as num_produto from produtos_em_pedidos join pedidos on (id = produto_id) where data > '2015-01-01' group by produto_id
```

Para obter a quantidade de pedidos, a seguinte query pode ser utilizada:

```
select sum(quantidade) as total, produto_id from produtos_em_pedidos join pedidos on (id = produto_id) where data > '2015-01-01'  group by produto_id
```

Juntando ambas você vai conseguir as informações que deseja. A query final ficaria:

```
select vendas.produto_id, num_produto * total from (select produto_id, count(produto_id) as num_produto from produtos_em_pedidos join pedidos on (id = produto_id) where data > '2015-01-01' group by produto_id) vendas join (select sum(quantidade) as total, produto_id from produtos_em_pedidos join pedidos on (id = produto_id) where data > '2015-01-01'  group by produto_id) quantidades using (produto_id) order by num_produto desc;
```

Veja alguns testes que executei para avaliar a query elaborada:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]